# Which of the following use of anchor is correct in regex using grep?

Tags: regex, grep

Both of the below commands gives the same output,
however which one is the correct method to use it?

```
grep ^'\<that\>' file.txt
```

Searches for the line which has that as the first word

```
grep '^\<that\>' file.txt
```

Same output as the previous one.

Whats the difference in placing ^ anchor before the quotes or inside the quotes?
Which one is the appropriate one?

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes prevent your command interpreter (shell) from replacing special characters (like '*' or '?' or '!') with expanded content. Since '^' is not one of the characters that your shell will expand, there is no difference between two examples you provided.